# React Redux Action is acting strangely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm using redux, and one of my action (ADD_DESIGN) is updating the state very strangely.

It is supposed to add object(I checked the action.payload, it is all good), to array(state.designs). But it somehow manages, not just to add that object, but add some other objects from state.design_sets.designs, and push them also. See picture please... If someone has any idea what could cause such a behavior, please help.

[State, and Actions being dispatched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndUQk.png)

```
 case ADD_DESIGN:

  return {
    ...state,
    designs: [...state.designs, action.payload]
  };
```

I dispatch the action here:

```
export const addDesign = (id, file, designData, previewData) => 
dispatch => {

dispatch(setFileUpload(previewData));
axios
.get("/api/file-upload/generatepresignedurl")
.then(res => {
  if (res.data.success) {

    const fileuploadurl = res.data.urls[0];

    axios.put(fileuploadurl, file, config).then(() => {

      axios.post(`/api/designs/${id}`, postData).then(design => {
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_DESIGN,
          payload: design.data
        }),
          dispatch({
            type: CLEAR_FILE_UPLOAD,
            payload: previewData.id
          });
      });
    });
  }
})
```

UPLOAD Reducer is separated from "designs" etc (I'm using combine reducers)... Could those actions maybe mutate the state, and cause problems?

---------- **SOLVED** -----------

In my component for uploading file, I had this:

```
const { designs, design_sets } = this.props;


let fullDesignList = designs;
design_sets.forEach(design_set => {
  design_set.designs.forEach(design => {
    fullDesignList.push(design);
  });
});
```

Still not sure how could this mess up the state, but it does?

Comment: Can you provide some more code from your reducer

Comment: You might have a duplicate action/action with the same `type` which would add the wrong payload. Might want to check the action for `design_sets` as well

Comment: @AustinGreco I've just check, no duplicates...

Comment: @varoons Which part of the code do you think would be useful? I don't wanna post the whole reducer.. basically this is the only action I dispatched which could update that part of the state.

Comment: @FilipKostic can you log the value of both the state.designs and action.payload and post the result? Obviously, one of the arrays are being messed up somewhere and it would be helpful to know exactly where. Also, can you post the combine reducers code?

Comment: Please show the reducer(s) for `design_sets`.

Comment: Do one simple thing change one variable name  and check again whether they are affecting each other

Comment: @Noah Thanks for the tip, after bunch of console logs... I've found the problem

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help. Could you post your own solution for future people with the same question?